# php_memcache extension in not showing up in wamp extensions

Tags: memcached, wamp, php-extension

I have a copy of php_memcache.dll which I have placed in my C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext folder.
I have restarted the wamp.
But I don't see this in my extensions list in wamp.
why?

I even added extension=php_memcache.dll in php.ini file. but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

do you have an extension_dir set in your php.ini file?
all the other extensions are set in php.ini just like your memcache extension?
all the other extensions are in the ext folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in WAMP 2.4, running a simple Memcache test script worked from the command line, but not in the browser.

The answer turned out to be stunningly mundane: WAMP had two php.ini files, and I was editing the wrong one.

E.g. Apache used this one: c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini WAMP also had this one: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini

Putting the extension=php_memcache.dll in the correct .ini file fixed things.

My clue something like this was the problem was that phpInfo()'s loaded config file reported different values in the two cases.